# Making Data.Map a contravariant functor

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory

`Data.Map.Map` is not a contravariant functor because of `Ord key =>` constraint. But we can pack it with a helper function into an existential:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Profunctor

data MapPK k v where
    MapPK :: Ord i => (k -> i) -> M.Map i v -> MapPK k v

instance Profunctor MapPK where
    dimap f g (MapPK ff mm) = MapPK (f `lmap` ff) (g `fmap` mm)
```

I used `Profunctor`, but it's a technical detail: `lmap f = dimap f id` is a `contramap`. I also used `lmap` instance of `(->) a b`, sorry if it is confusing.

`MapPK` is useful in practice - it's essentially a map with computed keys, so it wastes CPU cycles but may save space. We can implement `Data.Map.lookup` for it:

```
lookupPK k (MapPK f m) = M.lookup (f k) m
```

I want to turn this idea into a library. Any tips on modern key-value container interface? For `MapPK` to be generally useful more functions should be implemented (e.g. insertion-deletion).

However reusing function names from `Data.Map` seems antique to me. Should I look at providing `Data.Lens.At` instances instead?

Upd: `Data.Containers.IsMap` from `mono-traversable` cannot be implemented, as there is no way to get the list of keys. Also folds/traversals cannot. We cannot even `show` our "map".

In a sense, `MapPK` is not a normal map any more, but falls into a category of weird map-like things along with `type FunctionalMap k v = k -> Maybe v`.

Enumeration of values while possible is not very useful. if `f = const 5`, the map contains at most one value, so most of the values in the internal `Data.Map` are garbage but we cannot know that.

And even if we could magically invert `f` that won't help us much as the inverse does not always exist and even if it is there are problems with non-monotonic `f` that happen to have an inverse.

Note that we also gain some capabilities. Unlike `FunctionalMap`, our `insert` can be implemented just as efficiently as it is in `Data.Map`. And unlike `Data.Map`, some exotic keys are possible - now we can have functions as keys. But not all - `IO Int` is possible to use as a "key" in `FunctionalMap`, but not in `MapPK`.

Comment: Something makes me think you might appreciate the `MemoTrie` package.

Comment: Should the question be moved elsewhere if it's not suitable here? E.g. to CodeReview SO?

Comment: Definitely not code review.

Comment: I'm not sure this can fully work. How would you dump all key-value pairs of such a map? For example, how would `show` work?

Comment: Updated the question. `MapPK` cannot fully work as we lose some old capabilities like showing/enumeration/traversals. We gain some new capabilities so the construction is not necessarily useless.